# Onlyoffice doc to html conversion

Tags: file-conversion, onlyoffice

I am working with onlyoffice document server and it provides conversion from html to docx but is that possible to convert vice versa i.e. (**docx to html**)?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is impossible in this version.
Conversion to HTML will be released soon.
The only way to get HTML output in the current version is "File>>Download as" in the Document Editor's interface where HTML is listed as one of the supported output formats.

Comment: Do you have api to do this?